# Zend_Form array notation and empty elements names

Tags: zend-form, zend-form-sub-form

I'want to render:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="foo[]" />
<input type="text" value="" name="bar[]" />
```

but Zend_Form_Element require a (string) name, so I need to do:

```
$this->addElement('text', '1', array(
    'belongsTo' => 'foo'
));

$this->addElement('text', '2', array(
    'belongsTo' => 'bar'
));
```

but the output is:

```
<input id="foo-1" type="text" value="" name="foo[1]" />
<input id="bar-2"  type="text" value="" name="bar[2]" />
```

I can also accept an output like:

```
<input id="foo-1" type="text" value="" name="foo[1]" />
<input id="bar-1"  type="text" value="" name="bar[1]" />
```

but Zend_Form_Element rewrite elements with the same name

is there a way to do what I need?

Comment: I want the same! Please let me know if you solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For multiple values:

```
$foo = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('foo');
// Other parameters
$foo->setIsArray(TRUE);
$this->addElement($foo);
```

Generates: `name="foo[]"`

--

If you're looking for given keys such as `name="foo[bar]"`, use:

```
$bar= new Zend_Form_Element_Text('bar');
// Other parameters
$bar->setBelongsTo('foo');
$this->addElement($bar);
```

--

Tested on ZF 1.11.5

Answer (score 0):

class MyFooForm extends Zend_Form {
          public function init() {
          $fullNameOpts = array(
                   'required'=>false,
                   'label'=>'fullName',
                   'isArray'=>true,
                   'validators' =>  array( array('stringLength', false, array(1, 250) ) )
          );
     $this->addElement('text' ,'fullName',$fullNameOpts);
     // rest of the elements , forms and stuff goes here
          }
     }

And that does creates

```
<dd id="fullName-element"><input type="text" class="inputAccesible" value="" id="fullName"name="fullName[]"></dd>
```

It's on Element.php , in Form , line 512 "isArray" check.
I'm using a regular zend_form, crossValidation with custom validators and i'm pushing subforms to replicate the main form, 'cause the user can add multiple times the same form.
Additionally , I'm *too* lazy to research custom decorators, i have created one, but it kills subForms and array notation, so i just stick with the regular ones, and that solves it.

I'm at Zf 1.10.

Comment: But generally, when we make use of empty array notation, we have many fields with the same name. If you try to create a new element with the same name expecting a new field fullName[] this does not work

Comment: Post some code and I'll give  you a hand :).
I made a lib to deal with this, and my next goal is particularly that.
You have one form, and you want to *replicate* only 1 element of the form.